# Proxy configuration using local-entry or properties

Tags: wso2-esb

I have configured proxy with following xml:

```xml
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///data/queues/documents-validation</parameter>
```

But I would like to use something more manageable than hard coded value. Maybe something like

```xml
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI" expression="get-property('source.uri')" />
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked myself the same questions a couple of weeks. Unfortunately there's no way to achive this when you want to pick up files. I was told that this will work in version 4.9.

If you want to have this when you write files than this is no problem. You just need to set the 'to' header parameter and then call the send mediator.

Example:

Regards
Martin

Comment: Somehow it doesn't pick up the code. Hope this works now.

Comment: <property name="final_target_folder"
                   expression="fn:concat('vfs:file://C:/temp/wso2/sp4out/', get-property('transport','CLIENT_ID'))"/>
         <header name="To" expression="get-property('final_target_folder')"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <default/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>